# Creating Custom views which reference Current User's Team

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online

In CRM we have Goal entity. In that entity I want to create a View. For that I followed, Settings-> Cusomizations -> Customize the System-> Entities-> Goal-> View and clicked on New Button. While editing the filter criteria, I am able to set the Criteria as...

> "Goal owner" "Equals current User"

My Requirement is that I have to create a view with the following condition,

> "Goal Owner" "Equals current Users team"

But I cant find "Equals current Users team"

Any ideas on how to create this view?

Answer (score 1):

Does this give the results you wanted?
[image: Example Advanced Find definition]